# It is said that when we create an object of a sub-class automatically the objects of its super-classes get created. is it true?

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

it is said that when we create an `object` of a `sub-class` automatically the `objects` of its `super-classes` get created. is it true ? if yes then what if the super class is an abstract class.

Comment: This kind of depends on what you mean by `the objects of its super-classes get created`.

Comment: what internally happens when object of a subclass of abstract class created?

Comment: What _do_ you mean by "objects of its superclasses"??? Please clarify the question. There is no way to tell if you are talking (possibly) about fields declared in a superclass, or something else.

Comment: @RayToal : The object of super-class means object of Parent class having child sub classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not true. An object has only one type: the class that you instantiated. The object will also contain all the fields of the superclass, and it will be possible to call all the methods of the superclasses (that have not been overridden) on the object, but it is still only one object.

For example, say you have:

```
class A {
    int i;
}

class B extends A {
    int j;
}
```

If you instantiate `new B()`, you get *one* object that has storage for *two* fields, `i` and `j`.

Comment: +1 And this still happens even if the superclass is abstract (which just means the superclass couldn't be constructed on its own).

Answer (score 0):

The subclass "is-A" instance of the superclass, so it doesn't create a different object, your subclass instance *IS* the super class instance.